# FOS ckeditor hover label

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm using the FOS ckeditor in Sonata from the formatter bundle. When I hover over the body of a WYSIWYG editor the following label comes up:

[Ckeditor Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TobrF.png)

I'd like to disable this from happening, does anyone know how? I've tried various attributes on the form field and none seem to disable it.

See my config below:

```
fos_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        minimal:
            toolbar:
            - [Bold, Italic, Underline,
               -, Cut, Copy, Paste, PasteText, PasteFromWord,
               -, Undo, Redo,
               -, NumberedList, BulletedList,
               -, Blockquote,
               -, Link, Unlink]
            - [Maximize]
```

and the field:

```
->add('content', SimpleFormatterType::class, [
    'format' => 'richhtml',
    'ckeditor_context' => 'minimal',
])
```